# Custom select element in Form::select laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there a way to insert an  element in front of the list generated with: 
`Form::select('name', Model::lists('name', 'id'), null, [])`? For example I would like to put an `<option>` element like:

```
<option value="">please choose</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can simply add an element to the array of options:

```
$options = ['' => 'Please choose'] + Model::lists('name', 'id');
```

Ideally I would do this in the controller but you can also do it directly in the `Form::select()`:

```
{{ Form::select('name', ['' => 'Please choose'] + Model::lists('name', 'id')) }}
```

Note that you don't have to pass `null, []` since that are the default values of these arguments.